# Made to Measure - static block in product page

Tags: magento

I need to create a way for the buyer to input his/her sizes so that the ordered product is made for his measures. How can I do that in Magento 1.9? 
I was thinking that upon "made to measure" radio button is switched, a popup image and table emerges and the buyer fills some fields with dimensions that are sent in a text form with the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating Custom option on the Product.You shoule create custom option of text box so that user can enter his/her value.

Comment: Thank you, but the custom options box is out of the question because we're asking for 20-30 dimensions, and will look like a big big list that ruins the design. That's why I need a pop-up or something to activate only when a certain radio box is switched ON.